# How do make numericInput and selectInput next to each other

Tags: r, shiny

How do I make `numericInput` and `selectInput` next to each other instead of under each other? It is possible?

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    column(4,
           
         wellPanel(
           numericInput("weight1", label = h4("Weight 1"), min = 0, max = 1, value = NA, step = 0.1),
           
           selectInput("maxmin", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize"),choices = list("Maximize " = 1, "Minimize" = 2), 
                       selected = ""))),

  hr(),
  
  column(8,
         tabsetPanel(tabPanel("table1", DTOutput('table1')))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splitLayout` can be used to split the space.

```
wellPanel(
   splitLayout(
       numericInput("weight1", label = h4("Weight 1"), min = 0, max = 1, value = NA, step = 0.1),
       selectInput("maxmin", label = h4("Maximize or Minimize"),choices = list("Maximize " = 1, "Minimize" = 2), 
                         selected = "")))
```

The above code will produce equally sized inputs, but there is an optional argument, `cellWidths`, that can be used to specify the widths if another ratio is preferred. For example, adding `cellWidths = c("40%", "60%")` will make weight1 take 40% of the available space and maxmin the rest 60%.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's it. A question: do you know how to insert arrow, I wanted to put, for example: Maximize and then an up arrow.

Comment: do you mean just next to the word maximize, in the selectInput label? If yes, you can add it to the label: `h4("Maximize ",HTML('&#8593;')," or Minimize")`

Comment: I actually thought of inserting in the choices option. Another thing is not missing a `"`?